# How I can remove admob app ad serving limit?

Tags: android, admob

When I put my apps on Admob account all apps went ready ,But one of my apps is ready status and Admob sent "approved email".(but limited for ad serving ) .See match rates as below.

[image: See match rate as below.]

What can I do for removing this limit? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement only one Ad in starting screen or anywhere you feel suitable and remove all other ads. test it for few days, Google will analyze your traffic and your ads placement. If there are limmited Ads with a good placement strategy, and if you have a good luck, your limit will be removed.